# howto login with CustomUser

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

my application have two types of users Admin(not the admin of SuperUser) , Entrepreneur

i create 3 class CustomUser, Admin, Entrepreneur:
models.py

```
#user--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type=((1,"admin"),(2,"entrepreneur"))
    user_type=models.IntegerField(default=1,choices=user_type)
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True,blank=True)
    objects = UserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
#admin-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    date_naissance = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

# Entrepreneur----------------------------------------------------------------
class Entrepreneur(models.Model):
    user=  models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    date_naissance=models.DateField()
    adresse_entr=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    telephone=models.IntegerField()
    statut_social=(('ce','celébataire'),
                   ('ma','marié'),
                   ('di','divorcé'),
                   ('ve','veuf'),
                   )
    statut_social=models.CharField(default='ce',choices=statut_social,max_length=50)
    occupation=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    annnee_exp=models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

then i create a class form to use it for login 
forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model =CustomUser
        fields={'email','password'}
```

also a function for login and redirect to another home page
views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form =LoginForm()
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user=authenticate(request,email=email,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('home.html')
        else:
            messages.warning(request,'email ou mot de passe invalide')

    return render(request,'login.html')
```

in my login.html

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

/* Full-width inputs */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
.tabcontent button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Admin')">Admin</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Facilitateur')">Facilitateur</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Entrepreneur')">Entrepreneur</button>
</div>

<div id="Admin" class="tabcontent">
  <form  method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <h2> Vous ètes un Admin ?</h2>

  <div class="container" action >
    <input type="hidden"  name="user" value="1">
    <label for="email"><b>Votre Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Entrer Votre Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="password"><b>Mot de Passe</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Entrer Votre Mot de passe" name="password" required>
    <button type="submit" >Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> souviens de moi
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">annuler</button>
    <span class="psw">oublier <a href="#">mot de passe?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</div>

<div id="Facilitateur" class="tabcontent">
  <form  method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <h2> Vous ètes un Facilitateur ?</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <input type="hidden"  name="user" value="3">
    <label for="email"><b>Votre Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Entrer Votre Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="password"><b>Mot de Passe</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Entrer Votre Mot de passe" name="password" required>

    <button type="submit" >Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> souviens de moi
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">annuler</button>
    <span class="psw">Oublier <a href="#">Mot de passe?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</div>

<div id="Entrepreneur" class="tabcontent">
  <form  method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <h2> Vous ètes un Entrepreneur?</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="hidden"  name="user" value="2">
    <label for="email"><b>Votre Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Entrer Votre Email" name="email" required>
    <label for="psw"><b>Mot de Passe</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Entrer Votre Mot de passe" name="password" required>

    <button type="submit" >Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> souviens de moi
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">annuler</button>
    <span class="psw">Oublier <a href="#">Mot de passe?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</div>
```

i have 2 tabs(1 by type of user) and one login form for each tab
i want to login to the right place for each type of user
it didn't work correctly 
when i submit there is now redirection and it still in the same login.html page. I want if i submit as an admin it redirect me to administration page 
and if i submit as an entrepreneur it edirect to entrepreneur page 
what is my mistake?

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work correctly? Please include an error message or more elaboration about what is not working.

Comment: when i submit there is now redirection and it still in the same login.html page. I want if i submit as an admin it redirect me to administration page and if i submit as an entrepreneur it edirect to entrepreneur page

Answer (score 0):

You included no redirect command or context in your views.py file. for more on if statements read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm) and for more on context read [here.](https://riptutorial.com/django/example/3996/context-data)

Also, for future reference, Django follows an architecture patten similar to MVC architecture which makes problems like this rather easy to troubleshoot or at least locate (so that even if you can't solve the issue, you'll know quickly which files you should be looking at... and posting.) For more on Django architecture I recommend you start with [this.](https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-architecture/)

As for your more immediate problem, you can restructure your views.py to look like this:

```
#Views.py
def login(request):

    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated: 
        return redirect("home")

    if request.POST:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if CustomUser.user_type == '1':
                    return redirect('admin')
                elif CustomUser.user_type == '2':
                    return redirect('entrepreneur')
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm()

    context['login_form'] = form

    return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

Comment: I would like to clarify that this answer worked for you. If not, please let me know what the problem is.

Comment: thank you but id didn't work it stil return back to login page also i'm forced to change 'redirect' by 'render' because he send to me page not found

Comment: Add this in your setting LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = home.html